# PostgreSQL slow COUNT() - is trigger the only solution?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, count

I have a table with posts, which are categorized by:

- type
- tag
- language

All of those "categories" are stored in next tables (posts_types) and connected via next tables (posts_types_assignment).

[COUNTing in PostgreSQL is really slow](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) (i have more than 500k records in that table) and i need to get the number of posts categorized by any combination of type/tag/lang.

If i would solve it through triggers, it would be full of many multi-level loops, which really doesn't look like nice and is hard to maintenance.

Is there any other solution how to effectively get actual number of posts categorized in any type/tag/language?

Comment: Did you do an [explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-explain.html) to see the query plan?

Comment: @Sam Yes, i did, i guess (according to informations i've found on many places) this is problem of Postgre itself. Now i tried to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts" where was ~1 500 000 records and the COUNTing took ~9sec. At second time (Postgre probably caches the query, or something) it took ~2sec. Anyway, 2sec is even very slow i think.

Comment: Have you tried to create indexes? Don't forget about partial indexes. They can make a big performance difference if you only need to index a subset of the data. If you've done these obvious things and it still doesn't improve, I recommend you post more detail to get additional help (table schema, sample data, sample queries, explain plan, postgresql version, etc).

Comment: can we see the actual SQL that you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get this straight.

You have a table `posts`.  You have a table `posts_types`.  The two have a many to many join on `posts_types_assignment`.  And you have some query like this that is slow:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM posts p
  JOIN posts_types_assigment pta1
    ON p.id = pta1.post_id
  JOIN posts_types pt1
    ON pt1.id = pta1.post_type_id
      AND pt1.type = 'language'
      AND pt1.name = 'English'
  JOIN posts_types_assigment pta2
    ON p.id = pta2.post_id
  JOIN posts_types pt2
    ON pt2.id = pta2.post_type_id
      AND pt2.type = 'tag'
      AND pt2.name = 'awesome'
```

And you would like to know why it is painfully slow.

My first note is that PostgreSQL would have to do a lot less work if you had the identifiers in the `posts` table rather than in the joins.  But that is a moot issue, the decision has been made.

My more useful note is that I believe that PostgreSQL has a similar query optimizer to Oracle.  In which case to limit the combinatorial explosion of possible query plans that it has to consider, it only considers plans that start with some table, and then repeatedly joins on one more data set at a time.  However no such query plan will work here.  You can start with `pt1`, get 1 record, then go to `pta1`, get a bunch of records, join `p`, wind up with the same number of records, then join `pta2`, and now you get a huge number of records, then join to `pt2`, get just a few records.  Joining to `pta2` is the slow step, because the database has no idea which records you want, and therefore has to create a temporary result set for every combination of a post and a piece of metadata (type, language or tag) on it.

If this is indeed your problem, then the *right* plan looks like this.  Join `pt1` to `pta1`, put an index on it.  Join `pt2` to `pta2`, then join to the result of the first query, then join to `p`.  Then count.  This means that we don't get huge result sets.

If this the case, there is no way to tell the query optimizer that this once you want it to think up a new type of execution plan.  But there is a way to force it.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1
AS
SELECT pta*
FROM posts_types pt
  JOIN posts_types_assignment pta
    ON pt.id = pta.post_type_id
WHERE pt.type = 'language'
  AND pt.name = 'English';

CREATE INDEX idx1 ON t1 (post_id);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2
AS
SELECT pta*
FROM posts_types pt
  JOIN posts_types_assignment pta
    ON pt.id = pta.post_type_id
  JOIN t1
    ON t1.post_id = pta.post_id
WHERE pt.type = 'language'
  AND pt.name = 'English';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM posts p
  JOIN t1
    ON p.id = t1.post_id;
```

Barring random typos, etc, this is likely to perform somewhat better.  If it doesn't, double check the indexes on your tables.

Answer (score 1):

As btilly notes, and if he has correctly guessed the schema, the table design does not help - it seems (at first sight, at least) that, for example, to have three tables `posts_tag(post_id,tag)` `post_lang(post_id,lang)` `post_type(post_id,type)` would be more natural and much more efficient.

Apart from that (or in addition to that), one could think of a table or materialized view that summarizes all the possible countings, with columns `(lang,type,tag,nposts)`. Of course, to compute this in full would be VERY slow, but (apart from the first time) it can be done either in full "in background", at some intervals (if the data does not vary much, and if you don't require exact counts), or eagerly with triggers.
See for example [here](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views#Eager_Materialized_View)